Why Won't My Discord Client Sync Commands?
So I've had a live functioning discord bot for around 10 months now, various kinds of commands, some including Options and all has worked seamlessly including syncing commands.
Yesterday I tried to add some options to one of my commands, exactly how I have done in another command. After making the changes, I turned my bot off to run it locally to see if the changes are fine. My bot printed its statement Commands Synced to let me know its ready.. I refreshed discord.. My command isn't updated.. I also make a new test command... Doesn't show? What am I doing wrong? I also tried changing the presence to see if that would update and it did so I know some of it will continue to update
This is my command I wanted to change
Fortnite.py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import datetime
import requests
from typing import Literal
import os

TIME_MAPPING = {
    'Season': 'season',
    'Lifetime': 'lifetime',
}


async def fortnite(interaction: discord.Interaction, time: Literal['Season', 'Lifetime'],
                   name: str = None):
    try:
        if name is None:
            raise ValueError("Please provide a username.")

        if time is None:
            raise ValueError("Please provide a platform (Season, Lifetime).")

        time_window = TIME_MAPPING.get(time)
        if not api_platform:
            raise ValueError("Invalid time range. Please use Season or Lifetime")

        response = requests.get(
            f"https://fortnite-api.com/v2/stats/br/v2?timeWindow={time_window}&name={name}",
            headers={"Authorization": os.getenv('FORTNITE_API_KEY')}
        )

        response.raise_for_status()
        data = response.json()

        if 'data' not in data:
            raise ValueError("Invalid data structure in API response.")

        stats = data['data']
        account = stats['account']
        battle_pass = stats['battlePass']

        # Correct win rate calculation
        wins = stats['stats']['all']['overall']['wins']
        matches = stats['stats']['all']['overall']['matches']
        if matches > 0:
            calculated_win_rate = wins / matches
        else:
            calculated_win_rate = 0

        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Fortnite - {name}", color=0xdd4f7a,
                              url=f"https://fortnitetracker.com/profile/all/{name}")
        embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://seeklogo.com/images/F/fortnite-logo-1F7897BD1E-seeklogo.com.png")
        embed.add_field(name="Account", value=f"Name: {account['name']}\nLevel: {battle_pass['level']}", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Match Placements",
                        value=f"Victory Royales: {wins} \nTop 5: {stats['stats']['all']['overall']['top5']}\nTop 12: {stats['stats']['all']['overall']['top12']}",
                        inline=True)

        # Additional Stats
        embed.add_field(name="Kill Stats",
                        value=f"Kills/Deaths: {stats['stats']['all']['overall']['kills']:,}/{stats['stats']['all']['overall']['deaths']:,}\n"
                              f"KD Ratio: {stats['stats']['all']['overall']['kd']:.2f}\n"
                              f"Kills Per Minute: {stats['stats']['all']['overall']['killsPerMin']:.2f}\n"
                              f"Kills Per Match: {stats['stats']['all']['overall']['killsPerMatch']:.2f}\n"
                              f"Players Outlived: {stats['stats']['all']['overall']['playersOutlived']:,}",
                        inline=False)

        embed.add_field(name="Match Stats",
                        value=f"Total Matches Played: {matches:,}\n"
                              f"Win Rate: {calculated_win_rate:.2%}\n"
                              f"Total Score: {stats['stats']['all']['overall']['score']:,}\n"
                              f"Score Per Minute: {stats['stats']['all']['overall']['scorePerMin']:.0f}\n"
                              f"Score Per Match: {stats['stats']['all']['overall']['scorePerMatch']:.0f}\n"
                              f"Total Minutes Played: {stats['stats']['all']['overall']['minutesPlayed']:,}",
                        inline=True)

        embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.UTC)
        embed.set_footer(text="Built By Goldiez ❤️")
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        await interaction.response.send_message(
            "Sorry, I couldn't retrieve Fortnite stats at the moment. Please try again later.")

    except (KeyError, ValueError) as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        await interaction.response.send_message(
            "Failed to retrieve Fortnite stats. The Fortnite API is Currently Unavailable")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        await interaction.response.send_message(
            "Oops! An unexpected error occurred while processing your request. Please try again later.")


def setup(client):
    client.tree.command(
        name="fortnite", description="Check your Fortnite Player Stats"
    )(fortnite)

This is a command that has been working for a while for reference
Apex.py
import discord
import datetime
import requests
from typing import Literal
import os

PLATFORM_MAPPING = {
    'Xbox': 'xbl',
    'Playstation': 'psn',
    'Origin (PC)': 'origin',
}


async def apex(interaction: discord.Interaction, platform: Literal['Xbox', 'Playstation', 'Origin (PC)'],
               name: str = None):
    try:
        if name is None:
            raise ValueError("Please provide a username.")

        if platform is None:
            raise ValueError("Please provide a platform (Xbox, Playstation, Origin).")

        api_platform = PLATFORM_MAPPING.get(platform)
        if not api_platform:
            raise ValueError("Invalid platform. Please use Xbox, Playstation, or Origin.")

        response = requests.get(f"https://public-api.tracker.gg/v2/apex/standard/profile/{api_platform}/{name}",
                                headers={"TRN-Api-Key": os.getenv('TRN-Api-Key')})

        response.raise_for_status()

        data = response.json()

        if 'data' not in data or 'segments' not in data['data']:
            error_message = f"Invalid data structure in API response. Response: {data}"
            print(f"Error: {error_message}")
            raise ValueError(error_message)

        segments = data['data']['segments']

        if not segments:
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"No segments found for the given username: {name}")
            return

        lifetime = segments[0]['stats']
        ranked = segments[0]['stats']['rankScore']
        peak_rank = segments[0]['stats']['lifetimePeakRankScore']

        active_legend_name = data['data'].get('metadata', {}).get('activeLegendName', 'Unknown')
        active_legend_data = next(
            (legend for legend in segments if legend['metadata']['name'] == active_legend_name), None)

        # Helper function to get the percentile label
        def get_percentile_label(percentile):
            if percentile is not None:
                if percentile >= 90:
                    return ' Top'
                else:
                    return 'Top' if percentile >= 50 else 'Bottom'
            else:
                return 'N/A'

        def format_stat_value(stat_data):
            stat_value = stat_data.get('value')
            if stat_value is not None:
                percentile_label = get_percentile_label(stat_data.get('percentile', 0))
                percentile_value = int(stat_data.get('percentile', 0)) if percentile_label != 'N/A' else 0
                return f"{int(stat_value):,} ({percentile_label} {percentile_value}%)"
            else:
                return 'N/A'

        legend_color = active_legend_data.get('metadata', {}).get('legendColor', '#9B8651')
        # Create the embed at the beginning
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Apex Legends - {name}",
                              url=f"https://apex.tracker.gg/apex/profile/{api_platform}/{name}/overview",
                              color=int(legend_color[1:], 16))

        # Main lifetime stats
        level_data = lifetime.get('level', {})
        kills_data = lifetime.get('kills', {})
        damage_data = lifetime.get('damage', {})
        matches_played_data = lifetime.get('matchesPlayed', {})
        arena_winstreak_data = lifetime.get('arenaWinStreak', {})

        formatted_level = format_stat_value(level_data)
        formatted_kills = format_stat_value(kills_data)
        formatted_damage = format_stat_value(damage_data)
        formatted_matches_played = format_stat_value(matches_played_data)
        formatted_arena_winstreak = format_stat_value(arena_winstreak_data)

        # Legend stats
        if active_legend_data and 'stats' in active_legend_data:
            # Embed setup
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{active_legend_data['metadata']['portraitImageUrl']}")

            # Add fields to the embed only if the corresponding stats are available
            embed.add_field(name="Lifetime", value=f"Level: **{formatted_level}**"
                                                   f"\nKills: **{formatted_kills}**"
                                                   f"\nDamage: **{formatted_damage}**"
                                                   f"\nMatches Played: **{formatted_matches_played}**"
                                                   f"\nArena Winstreak: **{formatted_arena_winstreak}**", inline=True)

            # Add the dynamic fields to the embed
            embed_fields = []
            for stat_key, stat_data in active_legend_data['stats'].items():
                stat_name = stat_data.get('displayName', stat_key.capitalize())
                stat_value = int(stat_data.get('value', 0)) if stat_data.get('value') is not None else 0
                stat_percentile = stat_data.get('percentile', 0)

                field_str = f"{stat_name}: **{stat_value} ({get_percentile_label(stat_percentile)} {int(stat_percentile) if stat_percentile is not None else 0}%)**"
                embed_fields.append(field_str)

            # Add other fields to the embed
            embed.add_field(name="Current Rank",
                            value=f"**_Battle Royale Rank_**\n{ranked.get('metadata', {}).get('rankName', 0)}: **{int(ranked.get('value', 0)):,}**"
                                  f"\n# {int(ranked.get('rank', 0) or 0):,} • {int(ranked.get('percentile', 0) or 0)}%",
                            inline=True)

            embed.add_field(name="Peak Rank",
                            value=f"**_Battle Royale Rank_**\n{peak_rank.get('metadata', {}).get('rankName', 0)}: **{int(peak_rank.get('value', 0)):,}**",
                            inline=False)

            # Add the dynamic fields to the embed
            embed.add_field(name=f"{active_legend_name} - Currently Selected", value='\n'.join(embed_fields),
                            inline=False)

            embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.UTC)
            embed.set_footer(text="Built By Goldiez ❤️")
            await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)

            if not interaction.response.is_done():
                await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)

    except ValueError as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        if not interaction.response.is_done():
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"Oops! Something went wrong. {e}")

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        if not interaction.response.is_done():
            await interaction.response.send_message(
                "Sorry, I couldn't retrieve Apex Legends stats at the moment. Please try again later.")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        if not interaction.response.is_done():
            await interaction.response.send_message(
                "Oops! An unexpected error occurred while processing your request. Please try again later.")


def setup(client):
    client.tree.command(
        name="apex", description="Check your Apex Player Stats"
    )(apex)


This is my main file to run my bot and set up commands
bot.py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import asyncio
import logging
from commands import apex, league, fortnite, horoscope, help, review, tft, servers, kick
import re

# Load environment variables
load_dotenv()

# Get the blacklisted guild IDs from the environment variable
blacklisted_guilds = set(map(int, os.getenv('BLACKLISTED_GUILDS', None).split(','))) if os.getenv(
    'BLACKLISTED_GUILDS') else set()

logger = logging.getLogger('discord.gateway')
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)  # Maybe fix as server grows

# Create the bot instance
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", help_command=None, intents=intents)

# Setup command modules
apex.setup(client)
league.setup(client)
fortnite.setup(client)
horoscope.setup(client)
tft.setup(client)
# servers.setup(client)
# kick.setup(client)
help.setup(client)
review.setup(client)

# Regex pattern to match Discord invite links
invite_link_pattern = re.compile(r"(https?://)?(www\.)?(discord\.gg|discordapp\.com/invite)/[A-Za-z0-9]+")


# Event for when the bot is ready
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

    try:
        await client.wait_until_ready()  # Wait until the bot is fully connected
        print(f"Commands Synced")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    await update_presence()  # Call the function to set initial presence


# Function to update the bot's presence
async def update_presence():
    while True:
        guild_count = len(client.guilds)
        presence = discord.Activity(
            type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name=f"on {guild_count} servers")
        await client.change_presence(activity=presence)
        await asyncio.sleep(18000)  # Update every 5 hours


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    # Check if the message contains a Discord invite link
    if invite_link_pattern.search(message.content):
        await message.channel.send(
            "Need Horoscopes? Apex Stats? Fortnite Stats? LoL Stats? Idk Add me! <https://astrostats.vercel.app>")

    await client.process_commands(message)


# Event for handling interaction errors
@client.event
async def p_error(interaction: discord.Interaction, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArguments):
        await interaction.response.send_message('Missing required arguments.')


# Event for checking if the guild is blacklisted before joining
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    if guild.id in blacklisted_guilds:
        await guild.leave()
        print(f"Left blacklisted guild: {guild.name} ({guild.id})")


# Start the bot
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))

I have tried running locally, uploading the file to host to see if that changed it.. Closed, reopened, refreshed discord. I expected my Fortnite command to have 2 options in the same way my Apex command has 3 options.

Fixes Implemented

Explicit Command Syncing:
Previously, I relied on an implicit or automatic sync of commands which sometimes can be unreliable. Explicitly syncing the commands using client.tree.sync() ensures that all changes are pushed to Discord.

Command Registration Check:
Added a check to ensure the commands are registered properly with the bot's command tree. This involves ensuring that your commands are correctly set up and included in the bot’s command tree.

Command Definition and Registration:
Ensured that the fortnite command is correctly defined and registered with the command tree. This involved verifying that the function is correctly decorated and added to the command tree using the appropriate method.


Modified boy.py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

try:
    await client.wait_until_ready()  # Wait until the bot is fully connected

    # Explicitly sync the commands here
    await client.tree.sync()
    print("Commands Synced")

    print("Bot is ready.")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

await update_presence()  # Call the function to set initial presence

